# Item from SQLite database not deleting within RecyclerView

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite, android-recyclerview

I have a RecyclerView. When I click on the delete button, it removes an item from the RecyclerView but when I restart the app, the item comes back. Here is the function in my database class:

```
public boolean deleteList(long rowId) {
    return db.delete(DATABASE_TABLE, KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId, null) > 0;
}
```

Here is my adapter class with the delete button:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerViewViewHolder viewHolder, final int position) {
    viewHolder.name.setText(list.get(position).name);
    viewHolder.date.setText(list.get(position).date);
    viewHolder.delete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            RecyclerViewListSchema item = list.get(position);
            SQLiteDatabaseAdapter database = new SQLiteDatabaseAdapter(view.getContext());
            database.open();

            boolean deleteList = database.deleteList((long) position);
            list.remove(position);
            notifyItemRemoved(position);

            database.close();
        }
    });
}
```

*Update:*
I have added a commit function within my `deleteList` function as follows:

```
public boolean deleteList(long rowId) {
    db.beginTransaction();

    try {
        db.setTransactionSuccessful();
    }

    catch (Exception e) {
        Log.v("Commit", "Error: + " + e);
    }

    finally {
        db.endTransaction();
    }
    return db.delete(DATABASE_TABLE, KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId, null) > 0;
}
```

I am not getting anything in the Android Monitor either.
How can I fix this issue?

Comment: is the list populated from the database ? are you missing a commit ?

Comment: @dumb_terminal Yes. The list is populated from the database.

Comment: then definitely the item is not being removed from db. two things can exist here. 1. the delete logic is not successful. 2. the delete is successful but the change is not commited to db.

Comment: @dumb_terminal How do I do add the commit?

Comment: db.beginTransaction();
try {
    db.setTransactionSuccessful();
} catch {
    //Error in between database transaction 
} finally {
    db.endTransaction();
}

Comment: also check commitTransaction()

Comment: @dumb_terminal Do I add the code you provided me within my `deleteList` function?

Comment: In this case yes, it will be a start

Comment: @dumb_terminal Please see update in question

Comment: you should only remove the row from the list when the delete is successful. is the delete function returning true ? check it.

Comment: @dumb_terminal The function is returning false. I went into debugging mode and it was showing false.

Comment: then you should look for how to delete it properly. :)

Comment: Thanks for the help anyway! I appreciate it. I will try to find another way to delete the item, maybe as an SQLite query or using a similar method I have shown you. ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to delete by passing the value of the current item position. Of course it won't work! You need to try to get the item by its ID or by the name it has within the RecyclerView, the latter of which means that no item within your database and RecyclerView can have the same name. Try this within your database class:

```
public boolean deleteList(String name) {
    return db.delete(DATABASE_TABLE, KEY_NAME + "=" + name, null);
}
```

Within your adapter, call the same function but pass the current item text rather than its position in the RecyclerView.

Comment: Now it works. Originally, it would sometimes delete and other times, it just wouldn't.

Comment: That's because when you remove an item, the positions change and you were trying to delete the item with the wrong positions.